# How to make a Bootstrap list with text appearing in a block at the right

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

The screen is divided in two parts, vertically. So on the left side of the screen I want to have a list group with a list of chapters of a book, and on the right side of the screen I want a text block which is the full size of the right side, and in which text will appear. When the user clicks on a line in the list group on the left side of the screen, the text for that chapter then appears in the block of text at the right. And then when the user clicks on another line/chapter from the list group at the left, the text in the right block changes for the text from that chosen chapter. Does anyone have an example of making this work with bootstrap? Thanks

Comment: Just use a nav and anchor links to scroll to the right places in your text... No? Anyways voting to close since stackoverflow is here to help fix problems/errors not provide full solutions or reading content.

Comment: That is not what I want to do. I want the text to display to the right of the list group, and then when you click on a list group item, the text changes.

Comment: You would most probably have to use Ajax to do this. Once the user clicks on the chapter on the left side of the screen, make an ajax request to pull the text for that chapter and replace the text on the right side of the screen with the data that is pulled.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to an example using Ajax in this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/list-group/#javascript-behavior) refer the documentation. Hope you get what you want.